# How can I create an alias to a property within a Repeater?

Tags: repeater, qml

This code:

```js
Repeater {
    id: myImageArr
    property alias changeSource: imageElement
    model: 3
    Image {
        id: imageElement
    }
}
```

gives me an error:

> Invalid alias reference. Unable to find id "imageElement"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Image` inside the repeater is dynamically created depending on the model, so you can't refer it directly by id. If your model is a fixed value (3), then you can access the `Image` instance by using [`Repeater.itemAt(index)`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qml-repeater.html#itemAt-method) function. For example, to create alias to the first `Image` created by repeater:

```
property alias changeSource: myImageArr.itemAt(0)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for my code.  I get a: `Invalid alias reference. An alias reference must be specified as <id>, <id>.<property> or <id>.<value property>.<property>\n"` error.  @Mitch can you confirm whether or not this works?