# Aliases on styles

Tags: qt, button, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

Why cannot define aliases for Styles? For instance

```
Button {

    property alias color: theText.color

    style: ButtonStyle {
        label: Text {
            id: theThext  
        }
    }
}
```

gives an

> qml invalid alias reference unable to find id for `theText`

Comment: Sort of relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345552/how-to-create-alias-inside-repeater-elemets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similarly to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14351747/904422), it's because the item that the `alias` refers to is loaded dynamically. Style components like [`Label`](https://github.com/cedrus/qt/blob/master/qtquickcontrols/src/styles/Base/ButtonStyle.qml#L134) are just that: [`Component`s](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html). They are templates that are used to create the actual style `Item`s which are actually loaded with [`Loader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html).

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution (working example):

```
//MyCustomBtn.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2

Button {
    function setFontColor(fontColor){color_ = fontColor}
    property string color_: "black"

    style: ButtonStyle {
        label: Text {
            color: color_
            text: control.text
        }
    }
}

//MyTest.qml
MyCustomBtn {
    text: qsTr("Hello World")
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

    Component.onCompleted: setFontColor("red")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With default font size

```
Button {
    property int fontPixelSize: 0
    style: ButtonStyle {
        label: Text {
            font.pixelSize: fontPixelSize ? fontPixelSize : font.pixelSize
            text: control.text
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to get control's property just like the text.
You can even save this style to separate style file and set the control's labelColor property.

```
Button {
    property string labelColor: "yellow"
    text: "hede"
    style: ButtonStyle {
        label: Text {
            color: control.labelColor
            text: control.text
        }
    }
}
```